# What is the most effective thing that has worked for you in getting rid of acne (any kind)?

Tags: effectiveness, topical-cream-gel, acne, face, cystic-acne

This seems like the oldest problem that mankind has ever faced since the dawn of our beauty-driven world. I'd like to hear practical tips, products, or treatments that has worked for you, best if consistently.

Comment: If you ask for people's personal opinion, thus question would be of off-topic here. Please reformulate it!

Comment: This answer is also likely to draw attention to product placement and similar spam.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an opinion poll.

Answer (score -2):

Natural pearl powder has done wonders for me. My skin has cleared up and gotten brighter. It can be taken topically or ingested.